# Golang Error with Backing up the DBmssql: BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally

Tags: sql-server, go, backup

I am trying to do a full backup for an MSSQL database using go.

However, I tested the connection to the MSSQL server and it works like charm!

By executing also a query into the code `SELECT @@VERSION`

It gives me the version and that has been connected to mssql using the credentials in the code below.

By running a query `BACKUP DATABASE name_db TO DISK = '/tmp/database.bak'` it fails with the following error

> Error with Backing up the DBmssql: BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally

I am sure that I am missing something, any ideas/thoughts would be much appreciated.

BTW, I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and the mssql is installed there, I am using go version 1.9.

This is my code:

```
package main                                                                    
  import (                                                                      
     _ "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb"                                       
     "database/sql"                                                             
     "context"                                                                  
     "log"                                                                      
     "fmt" )                                                                    


var server = "server_url"                                     
var port = 1433                                                                 
var user = "user"                                                          
var password = "pass"                                                  

var db *sql.DB                                                                  

func main() {                                                                   
        var err error                                                                                                                                           
        // Create connection string                                               
        connString := fmt.Sprintf("server=%s;user id=%s;password=%s;
        port=%d", server, user, password, port)                                   
        // Create connection pool                                                 
        db, err = sql.Open("sqlserver", connString)                             
        if err != nil {                                                         
                log.Fatal("Error creating connection pool: " 
                + err.Error())     
        }                                                                       
     log.Printf("Connected!\n")                                                 
     defer db.Close()                                                           

        Backup()                                                                
        //Restore()                                                             
 }                                                                              

func Backup(){                                                                  
        ctx := context.Background()                                                                                                                     
        err := db.PingContext(ctx)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("Error pinging database :( " + err.Error())
        }
        var result string
        err = db.QueryRowContext(ctx, "BACKUP DATABASE tempdb 
        TO DISK= '/tmp/Backup.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,
        SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10;").Scan(&result)
        //err = db.QueryRowContext(ctx, "select @@version").Scan(&result)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("Error with Backing up the DB", err.Error())
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s\n",result)

}
```

I have found the solution which is very silly.. You can find it in the 1st reply.

Comment: Is your Go application being executed in the same machine with *MSSQL*? Does the specified username has write permission to specified filename?

Comment: Yeah, they are both in the same os and yes the username has the appropriate permission to store the backup there.

Comment: What is the result when the query is executed through `sqlcmd`? Also, try to observe the content of MSSQL log (error or access log, etc).

Comment: You are right, I forget to mention that in the Q. I tried to backup using `sqlcmd` and it works properly. For the log files, I don't have any.. 
I try to see what the PID of MSSQL is doing by performing the following command `journalctl _PID=1234` and unfortunately, there is no entries related to my issue.

Comment: How if you remove the `STATS=10` from the query? One more thing, how if you replace the `db.QueryRowContext` with `db.ExecContext`?

Comment: Thanks for getting back!
I tried removing `STATS=10` but I am having the same behavior.
If I change `db.QueryRowContext` by `db.ExecContext` it gives me an error that the query is intended to return many values rather than one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was obvious though, the code is clean and working as expected.

The only issue was from MSSQL, where it have a specific value set for the timeout queries.

That's why I succeeded executing other SQL queries like: `SELECT @@VERSION` from the example above in the Q.

Though, I set the value of the timeout for remote queries to 0 this SQL query:

> EXEC SP_CONFIGURE 'remote query timeout', 0
>    reconfigure
>    EXEC sp_configure

The  0 in `remote query timeout` means that the timeout is unlimited.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was from MSSQL and os , try query first on SQL Server Management Studio to explane where problem come from.

now, change this :
(

> err = db.QueryRowContext(ctx, "BACKUP DATABASE tempdb
> TO DISK= '/tmp/Backup.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,
> SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10;").Scan(&result)

)
to
(

> err = db.QueryRowContext(ctx, "BACKUP DATABASE tempdb
> TO DISK= '/tmp/Backup.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,
> SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10;").Err()

)

becouse db.QueryRowContext expected to return at most one row
and backup Query dont return any row